# two different date formats

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

We have a small news site where each news has time and date of publication in the following format:

```
"2018-06-20T06:07:00.000+03:00"
```

We connected analytics to which we need to send time in the following format:

```
"Fri, 23 Feb 2018 15:00:00 +0200"
```

Tell me, please, how best to resolve this issue? We can refer this question to the server-side developer so that the request contains the date in the format we need, or we can do it on the front.

I still do not quite understand how to get the date corresponding to the date in the article, and then transform it into the desired format, but I think it is possible (and difficult)

Comment: I don't fully understand-- is the question simply how to consume one date format and convert it to another?  If so, I would highly recommend checking out [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)-- date parsing can be a bit of a pain, and moment handles most of it for you.  That said, it is a somewhat large library.

Comment: need to convert the finished date to a different format, not get a new one ...

Comment: It is definitely possible, and not difficult, if you use a library like the one @AlexanderNied recommended. It can take your date and format it however you like.

Comment: I do not see in the documentation of this library the ability to convert an existing date. Could you tell me, maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: If your date exists as a string like you show in your question, you will first have to [parse](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/) it, then you can use the resulting `moment` object to [format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) it.

Comment: thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As people suggested to me in the comments, the best solution using javascript is to use the library `moment.js`

The following code does the work I need.

```
moment("2018-06-20T06:07:00.000+03:00").format('ddd, D MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ');
```

Answer (score 2):

If they are using PHP you could try something like this:

```
$date = date_create_from_format("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uP", "2018-06-20T06:07:00.000+03:00");
echo date_format($date,'D, d M Y H:i:s O');
```

That should give you a date like:  Wed, 20 Jun 2018 06:07:00 +0300

That should work as long as the input date is always going to be of the same format.